# Django model inheritance: share table with parent model

Tags: django, django-models

We use `django.contrib.flatpages` in our project. At some point, a decision was made to extend the `django.contrib.flatpages.FlatPage` model by monkey patching two fields, which, at the time, didn't seem like a bad solution. Now we want to rewrite it by properly subclassing the model to make everything a bit more readable. However, we would also like to stick with the existing table for django flatpages like this:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'django_flatpage'
```

without creating additional tables, as it already has all the data (including two said fields), and we don't want to touch the database too much.

Now, to the question itself. Is there a clean way to do it? Also, we should be able to register this model in django admin, if that changes anything.